# Phrase for "speaking with reference"?

Tags: phrase-request

I want to talk about a practice in which you are obliged to cite trustworthy people or publication to discuss a topic, in contrast to merely talking about things that do not have original reason to be true--just guessing or common sense. I know already that **speaking with reference** is not an appropriate phrase for that but I just mentioned it in the title to be able to communicate the meaning I want. I guess a related appropriate phrase for me is **speaking with credibility** but this phrase does not explicitly mention the practice of citing references. I want something that does

Comment: authorized source? Or just authority?

Comment: @EhsanAbd You seem to answer your own question: "to cite" is right verb. See [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cite). Or are you looking for a term to describe the **requiring** of citations? Can you make your question a little more clear?

Comment: @P.E.Dant yes *requiring of citation* sounds good. I've been mulling over this and I guess a related appropriate phrase for me is **speaking with credibility** but this phrase does not explicitly mention the practice of citing references. I want something that does.

Comment: @EhsanAbd I'm afraid that there is no specific term for this in English. You could use the phrase "Fully referenced" to describe a paper, maybe. What is the word or term in your first language? Perhaps that will give someone an inspiration...

Comment: One possible word to describe your citing other people saying or writing something is *quote*. (But I'm not sure if this is what you want. It's not what you want exactly, I guess.)

Comment: Consider **authoritative**.

Answer (score 2):

If memory serves, my post-graduate professors used a few ways to describe what you're trying to say.

First, like @NVZ mentioned in the comments of your question, one possibility would be to ***speak authoritatively***, which implies *credibility through support of documentary evidence and the acceptance of authorities in the field*.

Additionally, I remember a phrase used by a post-graduate professor of mine. She warned us that we must ***speak with the weight of impeccable research*** or end up failing her class. This explicitly mentions the presence of research, and that such research is ***NOT*** vulnerable to attack, denial, or excuse (meaning that the research is objectively sound, logically valid, and absolutely accurate).

Still, while both phrases imply the presence of supporting evidence and citation, neither phrase explicitly mentions them.